# Override layout of "layout" folder for normal screen device

Tags: android, layout, screen

I implemented all layout files for hdpi devices. And put them in "layout" forder. Now I tested on a normal-screen device, and there's some screen I urgently need to change, because a required input field doesn't appear (because of the small screen).

What I did is create a folder called "layout-normal" and put there a copy of my layout file, and reduce in the copy everything a bit so it fits the screen. Now I have 2 problems and don't understand anything.

1. Both files point to the same source - when I open them I don't get 2 files, but only 1 with my modifications.
2. Ran this on the normal-screen device and it still looks like at the beginning.

Please help :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

layout-normal and just layout are the same. It is just the default layout

Ref: android developers site

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

..

```
Size    small   Resources for small size screens.
normal  Resources for normal size screens. (This is the baseline size.)
large   Resources for large size screens.
xlarge  Resources for extra large size screens.
```

Comment: Ok, so what I have to do then is put the original layout file in "layout-hdpi" or "layout-large" and create the modified one in "layout"